# Why is $3^{(x-5)} + 3^{(x-7)} + 3^{(x-9)} = 91$?

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-function, exponential-sum

So far I think that this is somehow related to that $(x-7) - (x-5) = (x-9) - (x-7) =  2$, but is it ?
What steps do you take to add $3^{x-5} + 3^{x-7} + 3^{x-9}$ up ?
 Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you aren't trying to prove $91\mid 3^{x-5}+3^{x-7}+3^{x-9}$ for all sufficiently large $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that:
\begin{align*}
3^{x-5} + 3^{x-7} + 3^{x-9}
&= 3^{4 + (x-9)} + 3^{2 + (x-9)} + 3^{x-9} \\
&= (3^4)3^{x-9} + (3^2)3^{x-9} + 3^{x-9} \\
&= (81)3^{x-9} + (9)3^{x-9} + (1)3^{x-9} \\
&= (81 + 9 + 1)3^{x-9} \\
&= (91)3^{x-9} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for writing the question wrong. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Benskey Please could you edit your question to what you meant (so that others understand what is going on, and so the answer matches the question)?

Answer (score 1):

It will be $91$ only if $x=9$, you have not specified what $x$ is, or do we have to find $x$?

In that case $3^{(x-5)} + 3^{(x-7)} + 3^{(x-9)} = 3^{(x-9)} (1+3^2+3^4)=3^{(x-9)}(91)=91 \implies x=9 $

Answer (score 0):

This is **false**.

Take $x=0$, then $3^{x-5} + 3^{x-7} + 3^{x-9}=\frac{1}{3^5}+\frac{1}{3^7}+\frac{1}{3^9}\neq91$

Comment: Originally the question was that the left side of this is equal to 45.5 + 22.75 + 11.375, but I managed to get that to 91.

Comment: was what? @Benskey